# Java socket-client with GUI

Tags: java, swing, sockets, networking, client

I am trying to build a client-socket application for my school project that lets you send a file to a server. I build it, I open the server and the server works correctly as it waits for connection. After I open the client and choose a file with **JFileChooser** and click send it works, as the server receives the file. But if I try to select a file and click send again it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

THE SERVER CODE:

```
public class NewServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8090);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
        Socket sock = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected!");

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        FileOutputStream fout = null;

        String ip = in.readUTF();
        String fileName = in.readUTF();
        System.out.println("User with IP " + ip + " is sending a file with name " + fileName);
        fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

        System.out.println("Receiving file...");
        int count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        System.out.println("File received!");
        out.close();
        in.close();
        fout.close();

    }
}
```

}

THE GUI:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

Frame() throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Client");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 400);
    Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 8090);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton send = new JButton("Send File");
    JButton select = new JButton("Select File");
    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4, 5, 10));
    panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(select);
    panel.add(send);
    panel.add(label);
    send.setEnabled(false);


    select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            // optionally set chooser options ...
            if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                label.setText(file.getName());
                send.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                send.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
    );
    send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            FileInputStream fin = null;
            DataInputStream in = null;
            DataOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                fin = new FileInputStream(label.getText());
                in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

                out.writeUTF(sock.getLocalAddress().toString());
                out.writeUTF(label.getText());
                out.flush();

                int count;
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                while ((count = fin.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.getMessage();
            } finally {
                try {
                    sock.close();
                    send.setEnabled(false);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.getMessage();
                }

            }

        }

    });

}
```

}

AND in the main i just create an instance of the GUI:

```
public class NewClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Frame frame = new Frame();

}
```

}

If anybody could help that would be awesome! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`sock.close();`

You close the socket after using it the first time.

You need to put

`Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 8090);`

within the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method of `send`.

```
send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 8090);
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        ...
```

Based on Gregoris feedback below I would suggest that the `actionPerformed` listener is not being invoked by the correct thread to create a socket, which is surprising if it is closing it.

Bottom line is a closed socket can't be reused, and this is definitely homework.

Comment: Hello sir, i tryed to do that but the program crashes when i click send it freezes!

Comment: Have you tried not closing it? When I say 'put' I mean move, maybe you are redeclaring the same variable? What is the error when it crashes?

Comment: Yes, if i dont close it it won't execute correctly :( If i move the command inside where u stated when i click send the button freezes and the whole program doesn't respond i have to close it with cltr alt del

Comment: It would help if you could repeat the errors. And also the imports so I don't have to fire up an IDE to tell me, just to get your errors.